# Why does win.setPosition('center') move the window to top-left?

Tags: windows, nwjs

I have this code which I execute after toggling fullscreen back from fullscreen to windowed mode:

```
win.setPosition('center');
```

The window consistently appears in top-left part of the screen -- not the middle.

The manual claims at http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#winsetpositionposition :

> position {String} the position of the window. There are three valid positions: null or center or mouse
> Move window to specified position. Currently only center is supported on all platforms, which will put window in the middle of the screen.

I tried "center" both quoted and unquoted, and even "centre" in case it was a typo in the manual.

For the record, the "mouse" value (which I don't want/need) also doesn't work; it seems to put the window in a random or semi-random place, far away from the cursor.

Windows 10. nwjs-v0.61.0-win-x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are creating the `win` variable like below:

```html
<script>
const win = nw.Window.get();

// Move window to top left of screen
win.moveTo(0, 0);

// Move window to middle of screen
win.setPosition('center');

// Manually move window to middle of screen
const screen = nw.Screens.screen[0].bounds;
const x = Math.floor((screen.width - win.width) / 2);
const y = Math.floor((screen.height - win.height) / 2);
win.moveTo(x, y);
</script>
```

You can use `nw.Screen.screens` to see dimensions of all the monitors if you wanted to move it to a different location.

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Screen#screenscreens
- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#winmovetox-y
- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#winsetpositionposition

Comment: I'm not sure why you put your answer the way you did, but the line `win.moveTo(0, 0);` just above the centre line fixed it for me. Which is very annoying and weird. I thank you, but I curse NW.js for being yet another broken, cryptic software product where things like this happens. Also, I'm not sure, but it seems like it very briefly sets itself to 0,0 before centering, so that's... not optimal. But I've basically given up hope on anything whatsoever working, ever.

Comment: To clarify, you do NOT need to do each of these, I was just demonstrating their approaches. All you should need is `nw.Window.get().setPosition('center')`. It is not cryptic at all, it is exactly how it is documented (tested on Win 10). You can also set the value in the `"Window"` object in the `package.json` as `"position": "center"` (also in the documentation).

Comment: But the whole point of my question is that it isn't enough. I'm even more confused by your comment than I was when you only had provided the answer (which solved it, perhaps by pure coincidence?)...